# Django ManyToManyField relationship

Tags: django, django-admin, many-to-many, django-orm

I have the following Django model:

```
class opetest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True)
```

This m2m relationship is available on User object as 'opetest_set'.
How can I make available to edit this m2m relationship in django admin 'User edit page'?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To edit m2m in Django admin use [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects). In order to use your own `UserAdmin` you should unregister `User` first, like this:

```
admin.site.unregister(User)
admin.site.register(User, UserAdmin)
```

To make `opetest` accessible from `User` instance:

```
class opetest(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    people = models.ManyToManyField(User, blank=True, related_name='opetests')
```

Then `user.opetests.all()`

Comment: I've declared m2m field only in opetest model, but not extend User model. So how can I get access to this m2m relationship via User model?

Comment: >>> from django.contrib.auth.models import User
>>> a = User
>>> a.opetests.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'ManyRelatedObjectsDescriptor' object has no attribute 'all'

It's doesn't work.

Comment: @baobee Where does `a` come from? Is it `User` instance? Or you just assinging `User` class to it?

Comment: it was my mistake. But I get an error too:

>>> a = User.objects.filter(username = 'admin')
>>> a.opetests.all()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<console>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'opetests'

Comment: @baobee `a = User.objects.get(username='admin')`

Comment: Oh, thanks! It works! But can please also help me, how can I add this field as inline in django admin "User change page" ?

Comment: `class ProfileAdmin(UserAdmin):
    filter_horizontal = ('hrtests',)`

Comment: and I get an error: `'ProfileAdmin.filter_horizontal' refers to field 'opetests' that is missing from model 'User'.`

Comment: @baobee Use [`InlineModelAdmin`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects), I don't think it's possible to implement `filter_horizontal` as you want here.